# pg_start_backup and small max_wal_size

Tags: postgresql, backup, write-ahead-logging

What will happen, if `max_wal_size` gets exceeded during backup?

Specifically, let's consider the following scenario on master:

1. Set `max_wal_size` to a very low number.
2. Run `SELECT pg_start_backup('label', true);` to create a checkpoint.
3. Perform lots of transactions, so that `max_wal_size` is exceeded.

If I am right, PostgreSQL cannot process WAL files, because doing so would pollute the checkpoint. On the other hand, no new WAL files can be created, because of the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_wal_size` is a soft limit - under many scenarios it gets crossed. 
Specifically as for `pg_start_backup` it just commits and outputs the wal location - if you have archiving in place than you have nothing to worry about.

Starting the backup will create more wal files but doesn't prevent rolling them - that's why you need the archiving as all wal files generated in the duration of the backup are needed for a successful restore.

See: [max_wal_size documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-MAX-WAL-SIZE) 
Also: [backup documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Do I understand correctly, that _doesn't prevent rolling them_ means that right after ```pg_stop_backup``` all extra WAL files gets deleted, and this is why ```pg_basebackup --xlog-method=fetch``` can result in unusable backup?

Comment: Exactly, if you have low `max_wal_size` you are better off with the stream method. If streaming is not an option make sure to have the archive setup - then you could take the logs from archive.

Comment: One can also use replication slots: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS